# Virtual GPU in linux?

Tags: linux, nvidia

I'm not quite sure if this is the right list to ask, so please let me know if I should go somewhere else.

I'm in the process of planning/configuring what will be a compute cluster based on Debian 11 and [slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html). The idea is that all the nodes will boot over the network, thus coming up with identical configurations. Some of the nodes will be equipped with NVIDIA GPUs, and I am going to detect the hardware configuration at boot time (I've already figured out how).

But at the moment I am working mostly on VMs (virtualbox), so I'd like to be able to equip my VMs with a virtual that looks enough like an NVIDIA GPU that I can be confident that my boot time configuration loads the right things; it doesn't have to actually work as a GPU.

So, is there anything that would give this - a sort of 'stub GPU' without underlying hardware?

Comment: You’re not likely to get proper confirmation without using PCI passthrough to expose an actual GPU to the VM. And for NVIDIA hardware that means you need either their workstation grade hardware, or some complicated work to fake such hardware, because they take active steps to prevent usage of their consumer GPUs with VMs.